# What is a good substitute for an if else if in ComboBox?

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

I need to develop a Employee Payroll Computation for my exam.

[image]

I have successfully entered a code for when the Employee Number is chosen, there is a list of 1,2,3,4,5 and every number, a name appears on the Employee Name. I would like to know if there is another way to code it?

```
if (cmbEmployeeNum.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    txtEmployeeName.Text = "Sheldon Cooper";                
}

else if (cmbEmployeeNum.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    txtEmployeeName.Text = "Leonard Hofstadter";
}

else if (cmbEmployeeNum.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
    txtEmployeeName.Text = "Howard Wolowitz";
}

else if (cmbEmployeeNum.SelectedIndex == 3)
{
    txtEmployeeName.Text = "Raj Koothrappali";
}

else
{
    txtEmployeeName.Text = "Penny";
}
```

Also, Position Code is also in ComboBox. Do I only use the same code style because in position code, there is A, B, C and every code has an equivalent rate per day.

My teacher gave this final exam to us but he didn't really teach us the other lessons.

Comment: You can use a "switch" instead of all those else ifs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: Or a `Dictionary<int, string>`. Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: What text is shown in combobox? Mayhap a single line will do `txtEmployeeName.Text = cmbEmployeeNum.Text;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you're going to use the event of the `ComboBox` called `SelectedIndexChanged`, you don't have to use conditional statement to show all those names on your textbox.

You can store the names in an array and call those depends on the `SelectedIndex` of the combobox like below code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] names = { "Sheldon Cooper", "Leonard Hofstadter", "Howard Wolowitz" };
    txtEmployeeName.Text = names[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @MikaelaNera, you can upvote it and make it as answered for the others to know

Comment: can you please explain to me how this code works, about the selectedindex

Comment: @MikaelaNera `selectedindex` depends on what item you select on your combobox, if you choose the `first` item, then your `selectedindex` will be 0, if you choose the `second` item, then your `selectedindex` will be 1 and so on